# Allow user to select SQLite record from list of fields

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

This is my first attempt at writing an android app in Kotlin and I need a little help.

My app creates an SQLite db called 'BOPA_record' with two colums 'TOPIC_COL' and 'BOPA_COL'.

When two EditText fields are filled, the user clicks 'save' and the entries are written to the table.

This all works.

What I want now is a way to show the user the list of previous entries in the TOPIC_COL, when they click a button, and when they click a topic the record is displayed.

I've tried a few methods but I just can't get my head around them. As you can see, the method I've left in returns all of the entries as long strings (which isn't what I want!)

Here is my DBHelper class

```
package com.example.mytestapp

import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper

class DBHelper(context: Context, factory: SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory?) :
    SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION) {

    // method for creating a database by sqlite query
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        val query = ("CREATE TABLE "
                + TABLE_NAME
                + " ("
                + ID_COL
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + TOPIC_COl
                + " TEXT,"
                + BOPA_COL
                + " TEXT"
                + ")")

        // calling sqlite executing query
        db.execSQL(query)
    }
    // method to check if table already exists
    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME)
        onCreate(db)
    }

    // method for adding data to database
    fun addBOPA(topic : String, bopa : String ){

        // creating a content values variable
        val values = ContentValues()

        // inserting values in the form of key-value pair
        values.put(TOPIC_COl, topic)
        values.put(BOPA_COL, bopa)

        // creating a writable variable of database 
        val db = this.writableDatabase

        // all values inserted into database
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values)

        // closing database
        db.close()
    }

    // below method is to get all data from our database
    fun getName(): Cursor? {

        // creating a readable variable of our database
        val db = this.readableDatabase

        // below code returns a cursor to read data from the database
        return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null)
    }

    companion object{
        // defined variables for database
        private val DATABASE_NAME = "BOPA_record"
        private val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
        val TABLE_NAME = "bopa_table"
        val ID_COL = "id"
        val TOPIC_COl = "topic"
        val BOPA_COL = "bopa"
    }
}
```

and here is my MainActivity

```
Package com.example.mytestapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.mytestapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import java.util.jar.Attributes

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        //code to save bopa to database
        binding.saveBopaEntry.setOnClickListener {
            val db = DBHelper(this,null)
            val topic = binding.bopaTopic.text.toString()
            val bopa = binding.bopaContent.text.toString()
            db.addBOPA(topic,bopa)
            Toast.makeText(this, topic + " saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            binding.bopaTopic.text.clear()
            binding.bopaContent.text.clear()
        }

        //code to open previous entries from database
        binding.openBopaEntry.setOnClickListener {
            val db = DBHelper(this, null)
            val cursor = db.getName()
            cursor!!.moveToFirst()
            binding.bopaTopic.append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.TOPIC_COl)) + "\n")
            binding.bopaContent.append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.BOPA_COL)) + "\n")
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                binding.bopaTopic.append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.TOPIC_COl)) + "\n")
                binding.bopaContent.append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.BOPA_COL)) + "\n")
            }
            cursor.close()
        }


    }
}
```

Any  help greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: I highly recommend you to use Room for local database. Not only it makes working with SQL database so much easier, But also if you have questions it will be answered faster

Comment: Thanks Hamed, I'll have a look at that!